# AngularJS + RequireJS + Auth without relying on the routing

Tags: angularjs, authentication, requirejs

Is there a blog, project, gists or seed out there using angularjs and requirejs that provides authentication not based on routes?  I'm working on building a site that will show the user the same rendered view, but different data fed from the server based upon their authentication.  I have session handling already written into it, but I need angular to check the server for the session on the initial render for changing login buttons to logout and getting only the data the user wants to see that they've selected.

I attempted to use the angular run method to initially grab the session from the server, but when using requirejs, my app module doesn't exist at the time of calling the run method.

From my understanding, please correct me if I'm wrong, I should be creating an injector or using the $rootScope to carry the user information to routed controller and show the user what they is related to them.  If so, then I need to have a service that is initially fired during the project instantiation to retrieve the user's session data.  I'd prefer to not use the servers template rendering to put the users session data into javascript if possible.

Comment: I got this problem too, and we decided to send a cookie from the server containing the user auth on the first request. Then, in you can access it in your client. Might not be the best way though.

Comment: Have a look at this post (http://www.frederiknakstad.com/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/). Read the comments where they explain how/why they used a server cookie.